# Slow performance in adding points of a curve

Tags: python, optimization, cryptography, ecdsa

I need to optimize the code below. The point addition (p1 = p1 + s) is taking a lot of time.
Is there anything I can do to speed up the point addition? Maybe caching? Is there anyway I can speed up the module (tinyec) usage?

The add method used for `p1 = p1 + s` is defined here ([tinyec github](https://github.com/alexmgr/tinyec/blob/9a72bde3b77d2311f7a44dede573122f8b826687/tinyec/ec.py#L116))

```
from tinyec.ec import SubGroup, Curve

name = 'secp256k1'
p = 0xfffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffefffffc2f
n = 0xfffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffebaaedce6af48a03bbfd25e8cd0364141
a = 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
b = 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000007
g = (0x79be667ef9dcbbac55a06295ce870b07029bfcdb2dce28d959f2815b16f81798,
 0x483ada7726a3c4655da4fbfc0e1108a8fd17b448a68554199c47d08ffb10d4b8)
h = 1
curve = Curve(a, b, SubGroup(p, g, n, h), name)
s = curve.g

p1 = s

for j in range(1, 100000):
    p1 = p1 + s
```

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen according to [github page for this lib](https://github.com/alexmgr/tinyec/blob/9a72bde3b77d2311f7a44dede573122f8b826687/tinyec/ec.py#L116), s is not an int, but a Point object with its own _\_add_\_ method defined

Comment: Yes ure right.. is there anyway i can reduce the execution time of that method?

Comment: If the loop at the end of the code is intended to be for better timing precision: Note, that you always operate on different values for p1. This is not typical, can't be addressed by caching and I see no substance to the claim that the operation is slow.

Comment: I was just wondering if there is any way to speed up the point addition so that the loop runs quicker.